# Regular Expression for SFTP URL

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, url, sftp

In my application i am using angularjs and html5. The requirement is to get only sftp sites as URL. The default URL attribute of html5 allows http,https,sftp and ftp sites. I think using ng-pattern will solve this issue. But i am not sure about the pattern to be used. Can anyone help on this.

```
<input type="url" name="url" ng-model="user.url" required ng-pattern="sftp://.+"/>
 <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.url.$error.pattern">URL is in Invalid Format
  </span>
```

The error message for invalid url is not at all displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pattern is correct. Just use `ng-pattern="/sftp://.+/"`. The // will make the difference. The ng-pattern will accept parameters given within /../ braces.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pattern attribute of the input and write your own regular expression.
For example you can accept only strings that starts with sftp and have any following characters.
The validation for type="url" will remain and will guarantee that the url is valid.

`<input type="url" pattern="sftp://.+" />`